# iPhone: Opening Application Preferences Panel From App

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to open the application's preferences pane directly from the app, or will users be forced to to go through the Settings app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening the Settings app from another app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have to go through the Settings app.

An alternative is for you to replicate the settings within your application.

Answer (score 4):

The nicer alternative is to use [InAppSettingsKit](http://inappsettingskit.com) which does the replication for you.  Apple wants everybody to use the Settings app though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this on iOS 5.0 - 5.0.1.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible now in iOS 8

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL)
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```